# DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity

Tags: firebase, getter, firebase-realtime-database, case-sensitive

Every time I try to retrieve data from my database, I get

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: n
```

for any of my fields that are a single letter. Googling this issue gives 0 results and I can find no case incongruities in my code. I don't know if this is a bug in Firebase or if I have to do something special for any fields with names 1 character long.

Here is the rest of the error report if it makes a difference (the line of my code which it references is a simple

```
params = dataSnapshot.getValue(Parameters.class);
```

which works everywhere else:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: osu.gd_prototype, PID: 11345
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: n
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix$zza.zziw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix$zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzj(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
at osu.gd_prototype.DataSend$1.onDataChange(DataSend.java:107)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafp.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagp.zzSu(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzags$1.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code for parameters with the relevant offending getters and setters of the fields which throw the error:

```
public class Parameters {

    public int K;
    public double L;
    public int D;
    public int N;

    public Parameters() {

}

    public double getL(){
        return L;
    }
    public void setL(double lVal){
        L = lVal;
    }

    public int getK(){
        return K;
    }
    public void setK(int kVal){
        K = kVal;
    }

    public int getD(){
        return D;
    }
    public void setD(int dVal){
        D = dVal;
    }

    public int getN(){
        return N;
    }
    public void setN(int nVal){
        N = nVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the minimal code for `Parameters` that reproduces the problem please.

Comment: I think this should give you all the info

Comment: Ah... can you make the field non-public? E.g. `protected int N;` Or leave it public, but remove the `getN()` and `setN()` methods.

Comment: Setting all the fields to private seems to have fixed it, but I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: I'll write it into an answer.

Comment: Are you getting this error in release build with proguard on??

Answer (score 21):

The Firebase Database consider these items when serializing/deserializing JSON:

- public fields
- JavaBean-like property getters/setters

Since you have both a public field `N` and `getN()`/`setN()` methods, it considers the two in conflict. While in this case setting `N` and calling `setN()` leads to the same result, that may not always be the case. The chance of getting it wrong is too big, which is why the scenario is simply not allowed.

The error message is a bit of a red herring in this case. We should improve that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer was stuck in it for while until i found it :)

Comment: Thanks for info Mr @Frank van Puffelen.
My error has been resolved

Answer (score 4):

Convert the following fields from public to private

```
public int K;
public double L;
public int D;
public int N;
```

to

```
private int K;
private double L;
private int D;
private int N;
```

Comment: Changing the access modifier as private may create problem like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743661/firebase-no-properties-to-serialize-found-on-class I have faced the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found a different solution to keep my field `public String id` and at the same time have the method `public String getId()` which I needed to implement because of an interface: Simply mark the method with `@Exclude`, e.g.:

```
public class Group implements Identifiable<String>
{
    public String id;

    protected Group ()
    {
    }

    public Group ( String id )
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Exclude
    @Override
    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```