# How to retrieve data from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, real-time

I have been creating mobile application using Android and Firebase, I can't get data from firebase, the problem is in the line `Survey survey = ds.getValue(Survey.class);`, it work only when I delete attributes options and timestamp, Here is my code:

```
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference mRootReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference();
private DatabaseReference mSurveysReference=mRootReference.child("surveys");


    mSurveysReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Survey survey = ds.getValue(Survey.class);
                surveys.add(survey);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }
    });
```

[image]

```
    public class Survey {
    public boolean acceptAnonymousVotes;
    public boolean enabled;
    public String id;
    public String image;
    public Option[] options  ;
    public  boolean resultPublic;
    public Timestamp timeStamp;
    public  String title;
    public int totalComments;
    public int totalViews;
    public int totalVotes;
    public  String type;
    public String userId;
public Survey() {
}
}

public class Option {
   public int id ;
   public String title ;
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Have you checked related questions? like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462259/how-to-retrieve-the-data-firebase-3-0-database?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write , you need a default constructor that is required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(XY.class)

Also use `List<Option>` instead of `Options[]` for options.

Comment: it work only when I delete attributes options and timestamp, what I can do ?

Comment: Try to use long data type for timestamp and List<Option> for options (or maybe it should work if you initialize the options array like "public Option[] options = new Options[4]").

Comment: Whats your solution? Might help others :)

Comment: I have changed the type of attribute options to List<Option>