# Firebase Recycler View Encountering Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

**This is Error while app crashes as recycler view do not etch data and image**

**Error shown in logcat**

```
                                                          com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: age
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzst(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzj(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzd(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:147)
                                                                     at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:136)
                                                                     at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:176)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5768)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5801)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5037)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4913)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3260)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3069)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1505)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.access$400(RecyclerView.java:151)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:305)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:616)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

**Profile.java**

```
package mywork.com.firetest;

/**
 * Created by manighotra on 05-03-2017.
 */
public class Profile {

    String Name;
    String Age;
    String Image;

    public Profile(){

    }
    public Profile(String name, String age, String image) {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        Age = age;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        Image = image;
    }
}




**RecieverActivity.java**

package mywork.com.firetest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class RecieverActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView mrecyclerview;
    DatabaseReference mdatabase;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reciever);

        mrecyclerview= (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recy);
        mrecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Profile, ProfileViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Profile, ProfileViewHolder>(

                Profile.class,
                R.layout.profile_list,
                ProfileViewHolder.class,
                mdatabase
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ProfileViewHolder viewHolder, Profile model, int position) {

                viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
                viewHolder.setAge(model.getAge());
                viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());
            }
        };

        mrecyclerview.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }



    public static class ProfileViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mview;
        public ProfileViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mview = itemView;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {

            TextView Name_val = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.name_id);
            Name_val.setText(name);
        }
        public void setAge(String age) {

            TextView Age_val = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.age_id);
            Age_val.setText(age);
        }
        public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){

            ImageView img_shw = (ImageView)mview.findViewById(R.id.img_id);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(img_shw);

        }
    }

}



activity_reciever.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mywork.com.firetest.RecieverActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recy">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



</RelativeLayout>



profile_list.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:id="@+id/img_id"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/name_id"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="NAME HERE"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/age_id"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="AGE HERE"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801036/databaseexception-found-two-getters-or-fields-with-conflicting-case-sensitivity)

Comment: @Gourav maybe next time, you should explain your problem and include only code sample that RELATED to the problem. Because posting like this indicate too little effort spent. So why would we spent more effort to answer it?