# Android: Reading objects from Firebase causes application to crash

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Intro: *I am trying to build an android app that displays info about books (using Google books API).I have recently added firebase to the app.
At this moment I can log in or register to the app,I can search for books (with search view) and I have added a button for every book listed in the ListView that is created from the query.I added functionality to the button as it follows: the button (if pressed) should add the current book(in the Listview) to FireBase.*

My next step is to retrieve all the books added by users in another activity called **CatalogActivity**

```
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);
  GridView catalogListView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.CatalogGridList);

  final List<BookObject> books = new ArrayList<BookObject>();

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference();
    databaseReference.child("books").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
                BookObject book = child.getValue(BookObject.class);
                books.add(book);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    CatalogAdapter catalogAdapter = new CatalogAdapter(this, books);
    catalogListView.setAdapter(catalogAdapter);

    }
 }
```

For better understanding this is the **Firebase Data tab:**
[image]

When I run the app and I click on **CatalogActivity** the app crashes.

I have used debugging with break-points and I got to the following conclusions:

-database instance and reference are obtained correctly

-snapshot of all BookObjects is obtained correctly (`dataSnapshot`)

-first child snapshot (`child`) is obtained correctly ( could not tell if the first book is added to `books` as well)

-pressing F8 again: app jumps to Looper Class at loop method and my **app crashes**.

**What could be causing the app to crash?**

Gist of `BookObject` class:[BookObject](https://gist.github.com/catalinghita8/d7d659d157e78e3dd099584a7060fd5a)

Crash log:

```
07-31 22:40:38.308 15567-15567/com.example.android.booktrade_v10 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.android.booktrade_v10, PID: 15567
                                                                               com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: authors
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzhe(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzf(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.example.android.booktrade_v10.CatalogActivity$1.onDataChange(CatalogActivity.java:40)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.to.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.vj.zzHX(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

*Any help is highly appreciated.*

Comment: `Firebase causes application to crash`, firebase didn't.

Comment: post your crash log?

Comment: posting it now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37802772/886148 this could be the issue

Comment: Please add you pojo class

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added the gist link in the post

Comment: See my answer. I already posted why you came up with that error. HEY! It's you again. Didn't realize it was you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to change the names of your fileds with lower case like this:

```
public String title;
public String subtitle;
public String authors;
public String imageURL;
private String pushId;
```

Beside that you need to change also all your setters and getters like this:

```
public String getTitle() {return title;}
public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}

public String getSubtitle() {return subtitle;}
public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {this.subtitle = subtitle;}

public String getAuthors() {return authors;}
public void setAuthors(String authors) {this.authors = authors;}

public String getImageURL() {return imageURL;}
public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {this.imageURL = imageURL;}

public String getPushId() {return pushId;}
public void setPushId(String pushId) {this.pushId = pushId;}
```

Cătă, this changes will solve your problem for sure ;)

Comment: Thank you Alex and sorry for late response. I finally solved it on my own and I have to say I  did exactly what you said so even though I did it before your response I have to accept your answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can I ask you a question in chat? Thanks @AlexMamo

Comment: Sure. Let's use the chat.

Comment: My rep won't allow me to create new chat room.If you would be kind enough to make one and send an invite

Answer (score 2):

Change your declaration in Plain Old Java Object(POJO) class from

```
public String Title;
public String Subtitle;
public String Authors;
public String ImageURL;
```

to this

```
public String title;
public String subtitle;
public String authors;
public String imageURL;
```

Let me know if it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you @UmarZaii

Comment: @CatalinGhita No problem :)