# Error when showing to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to show data from my Firebase database to RecylerView and I'm following this tutorial http://www.programmingviral.com/firebase-recyclerview-tutorial/

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.biodatalist_layout);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rec);

        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer=new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);

        mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Biodata");
        mdatabase.keepSynced(true);

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BiodataModel, BiodataAdapter> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BiodataModel, BiodataAdapter>(
                        BiodataModel.class,
                        R.layout.biodata_list_row,
                        BiodataAdapter.class,
                        mdatabase
                )
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(final BiodataAdapter viewHolder,final BiodataModel model,
                                                      int position) {
                        viewHolder.setEmailtext(model.getEmail());
                        viewHolder.setFullnametext(model.getFullname());

                    }

                };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
```

and my `BiodataModel`

```
public class BiodataModel {

    public String Fullname,Email,NoTelp,Alamat;

    public BiodataModel() {

    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return Fullname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public String getNoTelp() {
        return NoTelp;
    }

    public String getAlamat() {
        return Alamat;
    }

    public void setFullname(String Fullname) {
        this.Fullname = Fullname;
    }

    public void setEmail(String Email) {
        this.Email = Email;
    }

    public void setNoTelp(String NoTelp) {
        this.NoTelp = NoTelp;
    }

    public void setAlamat(String Alamat) {
        this.Alamat = Alamat;
    }
}
```

when i run this activity . I get this error

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or
>   fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: alamat

my structure

[image]

How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your database, you have property: `alamat` with lowercase. But in the model class, you have the field `Alamat` with uppercase, both should be the same.

Change the field in the model class:

```
public String alamat;

public String getAlamat() {
    return alamat;
}

public void setAlamat(String alamat) {
    this.alamat = alamat;
}
```

Comment: please check my updated question. I'm adding picture

Comment: yes, you need to use lowercase alamat, and all the other fields also should be lowercase

Comment: Hhmm, where do you know that i have lowercase `alamat` ?

Comment: I'm new with this. Sorry

Comment: you dont, but you need to follow the javabean convention and it is to have lowercase fields. so like firstName, alamat to avoid this error..also check this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801036/databaseexception-found-two-getters-or-fields-with-conflicting-case-sensitivity

Comment: please upvote the answer since it helped you, thank you!

Comment: i get this warning `No setter/field for NoTelp found on class id.co.id.co.aaaa.BiodataModel (fields/setters are case sensitive!)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170267/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-yvs1102).

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the property names of the JSON in the database, and those of your Java class match exactly. Right now your `BiodataModel` class has a (JavaBean) property `alamat`, while the database contains a (JSON) property `Alamat`. Since the case of the first character is different, Firebase can't find a matching property on your object when it reads the data from the database.

As Peter showed, the easiest fix is to keep the exact same case between database and code. An alternative is to annotate your Java code with the correct spelling/casing of the JSON property:

```
public class BiodataModel {

    public String Fullname,Email,NoTelp,Alamat;

    public BiodataModel() {

    }

    @PropertyName("Fullname")
    public String getFullname() {
        return Fullname;
    }

    @PropertyName("Email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    @PropertyName("NoTelp")
    public String getNoTelp() {
        return NoTelp;
    }

    @PropertyName("Alamat")
    public String getAlamat() {
        return Alamat;
    }

    @PropertyName("Fullname")
    public void setFullname(String Fullname) {
        this.Fullname = Fullname;
    }

    @PropertyName("Email")
    public void setEmail(String Email) {
        this.Email = Email;
    }

    @PropertyName("NoTelp")
    public void setNoTelp(String NoTelp) {
        this.NoTelp = NoTelp;
    }

    @PropertyName("Alamat")
    public void setAlamat(String Alamat) {
        this.Alamat = Alamat;
    }
}
```

Note by the way that the getters and setters are optional, and don't seem to add much here. Since your fields are already public, you can also use this much shorter class:

```
public class BiodataModel {
    public String Fullname;
    public String Email;
    public String NoTelp;
    public String Alamat;
}
```

Since the field names here already precisely match the JSON property names, you don't need to annotate them. But if you ever have a mismatch here, you can just annotate the field to get things working again. For example:

```
public class BiodataModel {
    @PropertyName("FullName")
    public String Fullname;
    public String Email;
    public String NoTelp;
    public String Alamat;
}
```