# Firebase writes different files if app is debug or release version

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just found out something very odd with Firebase and I would like to know if it is me that's doing something wrong or if there is a solution to this problem.

Basically, this is what it has always written when I was developing the app (and it's precisely what I was expecting):

`nscoachtools@gmail¸com
    maxMatches: 60
    maxPlayers: 500
    maxTeams: 30
    userId: "SnMuRZEVqyN***...***hv2"
    userMail: "nscoachtools@gmail.com"
    userName: "Nicola Salvaro"
    userPicture: "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-L7lSPz0VJ9A/..."
    userToken: -1`

and this is what it writes after I built the app in release mode:

`nsalvaro77@gmail¸com
    a: "Nicola Salvaro"
    b: "ESjqwuh***...***wg1"
    c: "nsalvaro77@gmail.com"
    d: "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-2kwSEmLEN1c/..."
    e: -2
    f: 30
    g: 500
    h: 60
    userToken: 1499775285255`

Every "title" has been replaced with a letter. And "e: " was supposed to be "userToken: " then, when I tried to update it, it wrote it with the proper string but not on top of the original value... just wrote a new one. Then, when I try to read the full user, it gets the value of "e: ", not the "userToken: " one.

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In release mode your Android app is being minified by Proguard. This process strips unused methods and makes other method names shorter.

As a consequence, your POJO classes (the classes your read from/write to Firebase) are getting new method names and Firebase reflectively uses those method names to determine the properties in the JSON.

The solution is to tell Proguard to not modify the method names of your POJOs.

More on that:

- The oldest Q&A on how to do this is: [What ProGuard configuration do I need for Firebase on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273929/what-proguard-configuration-do-i-need-for-firebase-on-android). But that one is from Firebase 2.x, while many of these are auto-included in Firebase 9 and up.
- You can also potentially mark the classes with `@Keep`, see [Firebase No properties to serialize found on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743661/firebase-no-properties-to-serialize-found-on-class/41141406#41141406).
- More interesting Q&A on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-database%5D+proguard+release

Comment: Thank you!!! In my case it was sufficient to add the @Keep and everything worked perfectly! You saved my day!!

Comment: Good to hear this fixed your problem. I always forget about `@Keep`, while it indeed seems the fastest way to get this working. So this was a nice reminder for me too. :-)