# Using an interface with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I am implementing an interface called RowType for a handful of different classes let's say class A, B, and C. How would I iterate through Firebase to get each different object?

```
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        RowType rowType = snapshot.getValue(RowType.class);
                        Log.d("awdjk", "qwjel");
                    }
```

I would assume that since all the objects inserted in Firebase are of either class A, B, or C, that I could use RowType to get the snapshot value. However, I am getting an error saying that "No properties to serialize found on class RowType".

**UPDATE**

Interface

```
public interface RowType {
int EXERCISE_ROW = 0;
int REST_ROW = 1;
int SUPERSET_ROW = 2;
int PYRAMIDSET_ROW = 3;
int BUTTON_ROW = 4;
}
```

Exercise class

```
public class ExerciseModel implements RowType {
public String exercise, sets, reps, view, minutes, seconds, time, weight, childCount;
private EditText weightEditText, setsEditText, repsEditText;
private AutoCompleteTextView exerciseEditText;
private ImageView dragHandle;
private ExerciseRowTextWatcher exerciseRowTextWatcher;


public ExerciseRowTextWatcher getExerciseRowTextWatcher(){
    return exerciseRowTextWatcher;
}

public void setExerciseRowTextWatcher(ExerciseRowTextWatcher exerciseRowTextWatcher){
    this.exerciseRowTextWatcher = exerciseRowTextWatcher;
}


public ImageView getDragHandle(){
    return dragHandle;
}

public void setDragHandle(ImageView dragHandle){
    this.dragHandle = dragHandle;
}

public AutoCompleteTextView getExerciseEditText(){
    return exerciseEditText;
}

public void setExerciseEditText(AutoCompleteTextView exerciseEditText){
    this.exerciseEditText = exerciseEditText;
}

public EditText getWeightEditText(){
    return weightEditText;
}

public void setWeightEditText(EditText weightEditText){
    this.weightEditText = weightEditText;
}

public EditText getSetsEditText(){
    return setsEditText;
}

public void setSetsEditText(EditText setsEditText){
    this.setsEditText = setsEditText;
}

public EditText getRepsEditText(){
    return repsEditText;
}

public void setRepsEditText(EditText repsEditText){
    this.repsEditText = repsEditText;
}

public String getChildCount(){
    return childCount;
}

public void setChildCount(String childCount){
    this.childCount = childCount;
}

public String getExercise(){
    return exercise;
}

public String getWeight(){
    return weight;
}

public String getSets(){
    return sets;
}

public String getReps(){
    return reps;
}

public String getView(){
    return view;
}

public String getMinutes(){
    return minutes;
}

public String getSeconds(){
    return seconds;
}

public String getTime(){   return time;}

public void setExercise(String exercise){
    this.exercise = exercise;
}

public void setTime(String time){ this.time = time; }

public void setWeight(String weight){
    this.weight = weight;
}

public void setMinutes(String minutes){
    this.minutes = minutes;
}

public void setSeconds(String seconds){
    this.seconds = seconds;
}

public void setSets(String sets){
    this.sets = sets;
}

public void setView(String view){
    this.view = view;
}

public void setReps(String reps){
    this.reps = reps;
}

}
```

I have other classes that are implemented in the interface, but to keep this short, I have added only the exercise class. The other classes are relatively similar.

Comment: Check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743661/firebase-no-properties-to-serialize-found-on-class

Comment: Please add your class/interface code.

Comment: @AlexMamo I updated my code

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use as a model class, an interface. This is not possible because the model class must have the `public no-argument constructor` which is needed for Firebase. As we know, an interface cannot be initialized using the **`new`** keyword and therefore cannot have a constructor.

Why does Firebase need the no-argument constructor? When the Firebase Realtime Database SDK deserializes objects coming from the database, it requires that any objects in use have **`a public no-argument constructor`** that it can use to instantiate the object and this is not possible with an interface because the SDK doesn't really know how to create an instance of it.

Comment: So how would I check to see if the snapshot is of class Exercise, or another class?

Comment: snapshot.getValue().getClass().getName() returns a HashMap even though I inserted an object of class Exercise

Comment: That's correct because every node in Firebase is a `Map`. You are not getting the corresponding object of `Exercise` class because you are pointing on a wrong `DatabaseReference`. You need to attach a listener on the exact location where your `Exercise` class is mapped. Do you think that my answer helped you?