# Android Studio..Application Crashes when deployed apk

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

When i run my application directly from android studio with a real device..it works fine...but when i build apk and run it then during user registeration it crashes...

```html
public void storeDataToFirebase(){
        progressDialog.setMessage("Storing Data to Database");
        User user=new User(USERNAME,EMAIL,gender,AGE,NUMBER,BG,PASSWORD);
         userEmail=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();

        assert email != null;
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                   .child(userEmail.replace(".","_")).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                   if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                   else {
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data insertion failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }
           });

        }
```

LogCat...

muhammadobaid.blooddonationsystem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                             Process: com.example.muhammadobaid.blooddonationsystem, PID: 4273
                                                                                             com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class com.example.muhammadobaid.blooddonationsystem.Model.User
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzf(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbv(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at com.example.muhammadobaid.blooddonationsystem.MainActivity.storeDataToFirebase(MainActivity.java:111)
                                                                                                 at com.example.muhammadobaid.blooddonationsystem.MainActivity$1$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:57)
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6102)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)

Comment: it works fine when run from android studio using real device..

Answer (score 0):

```html
public class User {

    public String username;
    public String email;
    public String gender;
    public   String age;
    public String number;
    public String bloodGroup;
    public String password;

    public User(String username, String email, String gender, String age, String number, String bloodGroup, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;
        this.number = number;
        this.bloodGroup = bloodGroup;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I made my user class variables as public..Which solves my problem..

It Helps...[Firebase No properties to serialize found on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743661/firebase-no-properties-to-serialize-found-on-class)